# Show that $y[x_0,x_1,\ldots ,x_n]=0$

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation

Show using the Newton representation of interpolation polynomial that $y[x_0,x_1,\ldots ,x_n]=0$ if $y_i=p(x_i)$, $i=0,  \ldots , n$ for a polynomial $p$ of degree $n-1$.

The Newton representation of interpolation polynomial using the divided differences is \begin{align*}p(x)&=\sum_{i=0}^ny[x_0,x_1,\ldots ,x_i](x-x_0)\cdots (x-x_{i-1})\end{align*}

We have that
$$p(x)= y[x_0] + (x - x_0)y[x_0, x_1] + \ldots + \prod_{j = 0}^{n - 1} (x - x_j) y[x_0, \ldots, x_n]$$
Do we take $x=x_i$ for $0\leq i\leq n$ to get desired result?

Comment: You can identify derivatives and divided differences through the formula
$$
y[x_0,\cdots, x_n] = \dfrac{f^{(n)}(\xi)}{n!}.
$$
But in the end, a polynomial of degree $n-1$ cannot have a non zero coefficient of degree $n$.

Comment: Ahh and since $f$ is a polynomial of degree $n-1$ the $n$th derivative is equal to $0$, right? (By $f$ you mean the given $p$, right?) @PierreCarre

Comment: Do we use at the proof the fact that $y_i=p(x_i)$ ? @PierreCarre

Comment: No, if you just consider the interpolation formula you realize that if $y[x_0, \cdots ,x_n] \ne 0$ the polynomial would have degree $n$.

Comment: Ah ok! So the f in your notation is the p in the notation of above? @PierreCarre

Comment: Yes, $f$ is the function whose differences are being computed.

Comment: You use the condition $y_i=p(x_i)$, and presumably $y_i=y(x_i)$, to conclude that $y[x_0,x_1,...,x_n]=p[x_0,x_1,...,x_n]$.

Comment: Ah and then we use the fact that $$y[x_0,\cdots, x_n] =p[x_0,\cdots, x_n] = \dfrac{p^{(n)}(\xi)}{n!}$$ to get the desired result,right? @LutzLehmann

Comment: To show that $y[x_0,x_1,...,x_n]=p[x_0,x_1,...,x_n]$ do we have to use induction? @LutzLehmann

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $q$ be the unique polynomial of degree at most $n$ such that $q(x_i) = y(x_i)$ for $i = 0, 1, \dots, n$. Then by Newton's representation, we have
$$q(x) = \sum_{i = 0}^{n}y[x_0, \dots, x_i](x - x_0)\dots(x - x_{i - 1}).$$
By uniqueness, $q = p$. Therefore the coefficient of $x^n$ in $q(x)$ is $0$. This means exactly that
$$y[x_0, \dots, x_n] = 0.$$

Comment: Why do we have to consider a polynomial $q$ and show that $q=p$ ? Why can we not just take only $p$ ?

Comment: @MaryStar Yes you can just start with the Newton representation for $p$. $q$ is not necessary.

Comment: So we have : By Newton's representation, we have
$$p(x) = \sum_{i = 0}^{n}y[x_0, \dots, x_i](x - x_0)\dots(x - x_{i - 1}).$$
The coefficient of $x^n$ in $p(x)$ is $0$, since it is of degree $n-1$. This means that
$$y[x_0, \dots, x_n] = 0$$ right?

Comment: @MaryStar Yes it looks right.

Comment: Ok! Thank you very much!! :-)